# Start antivirus scan from a script on Azure Linux VM

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a shell script inside Azure Linux vm. The **Azure Linux VM** has **Sophos** installed in it.The shell script can scan the files present in a directory by using **savscan** command. Challenge is , we are using **azure data factory** pipeline, which needs to call the **azure function**. The azure function should be able to ssh to linux vm, and execute the script. The function should pass the parameters like file path  for the **azure shared file storage** where **Sophos** needs to perform the scan.

I understand thepipeline can call the **http triggered azure function**. But how can we ssh into a vm and run the scripts remotely from the azure function. Also the parameters for the file path will come from data factory.

```sh
inotifywait -mr -e close_write "/xyz/abc/" |
while read dir eve file; do
    echo "new file '$path$file' detected - start scan"
    savscan -eec $path$file
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo "1"
    else 
      echo "0"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I don't think Azure function can ssh into the VM.

Comment: @CharlesXu- Is there a way Azure function can call bash script,which in turn use ssh hostname to remote in to linux vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is something wrong with your `ScriptPath` param . If you are using Azure Automation, we can't place static script files in it , but we can download our script first and place it in "c:/temp" folder of Azure automation.

I did some tests on my side , I placed my scripts in Azure storage account , before I need to run this script, I will download it to Azure automation temp folder so that I can specify a path to run it .

Try the PS below in Automation:

```
$appid = "<your Azure application ID>"
$passwd = "<your Azure application password>"
$tenant = "<tenant>"


$storageName = "<storage name>"
$containerName = "<container name>"
$scrtptName = "<script name>"
$storageResourceGroupName = "<storage group name>"

$vmName = "<vm name>"
$VMResourceGroupName = "<vm group name>"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwd -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($appid , $secpasswd)
login-AzAccount -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenant  -ServicePrincipal

$storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $storageResourceGroupName -Name $storageName
Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Blob $scrtptName -Context $storage.Context -Destination "c:/temp"

$scriptPath = "c:/temp/$scrtptName" 

$result = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -VMname $vmName -ResourceGroupName $VMResourceGroupName  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $scriptPath
echo $result.Value

Remove-Item $scriptPath -Force
```

Modules I imported :
[image]

I place my script in my storage account, in this case , it is used for download something :
[image]

My test script content :

```
$url = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/7/1E7B1181-3974-4B29-9A47-CC857B271AA2/English/X64/msodbcsql.msi"
$outpath = "c:/odbc.msi"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outpath
```

**Test on Azure automation and its result :** 
[image]
[image]
As you can see the file has been download successfully .

Btw, there is no need to use remote powershell here , you can use run command feature of Azure VMs to run your scripts on Azure VMs directly .

Comment: Hi @RiaC , how's going ? Any further assistance needed ?

Comment: Hi Stanley,I tried doing as below(using Windows VM for now)-Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName '****' -VMName '****' -CommandId RunPowerShellScript -ScriptPath '****'.  The error that I get while trying to run this from Azure Automation runbook is as below-Invoke-AzVMCommand : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ScriptPath'. Also to let you know- I have enabled Azure PS remoting as :Enable-PSRemoting.module called Connect-AzureARMVMPS, but it is not supported by MSFT. Can someone help me with steps as to how do I remote in to the Windows/Linux to execute script

Comment: Hi @RiaC , I did some test for you and  updated my answer , hope it helps .

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine with Linux as well. Just for everyone's info- I want to add that I had to create a NewContext before using Get-AzureStorageBlobContent.

Comment: Hi @RiaC , yes , you have to make sure that the user or sp has permission to access your storage account in this scenario .Anyway Glad to know it works for you .So could you pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark this answer so that it will help others who has similar issues and it will be an award for me : ) have a nice day !

Comment: Hi @RiaC, if my answer is helpful for you, pls mark it as an answer. If you mark helpful answers each time, more people will be glad to assist you.

Comment: Thank you Stanley. I guess I marked the answer right. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Nice work Stanley, I will test it too on an Ubuntu Machine. Hope it works :)

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: This is not an answer. should be added as comments